# Nvim-dap: Debug adapter didn't respond. OpenDebugAD7.exe 'waiting for v8 protocol on stdin/stdout'

Tags: c++, debugging, neovim, neovim-plugin

I have configured nvim-dap for c++ with the following configuration:

```
dap.adapters.cppdbg = {
     name = 'cppdbg',
    type = 'executable',
    command = vim.fn.stdpath('data') .. '/mason/bin/OpenDebugAD7.cmd',
}

dap.configurations.cpp = {
    {
      name = 'Debug Program',
      type = 'cppdbg',
      request = 'launch',
      MIMode = 'lldb',
      cwd = '${workspaceFolder}',
      stopAtEntry = true,
      program = function ()
        return vim.fn.input("Path to executable: ", vim.fn.getcwd() .. '/', 'file')
      end,
    }
}
```

but nvim-dap will still not start.

Idk have spent days trying to figure it out but to no avail. When I run nvim-dap the following message appears after a while `Debug adapter didn't respond. Either the adapter is slow (then wait and ignore this) or there is a problem with your adapter or` cppdbg `configuration. Check the logs for errors (:help dap.set_log_level)`. A console also pops up saying `waiting for v8 protocol on stdin/stdout`.

Comment: Have you tried asking at `nvim-dap` discussions? https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap/discussions

Answer (score 0):

- You may use **lldb-mi** as MIDebugger (by appending entry `MIDebuggerPath = '/path/to/lldb-mi'`)
- Or you could use **lldb-vscode** as adapter so that there is no need to install lldb-mi: https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap/wiki/Debug-Adapter-installation#ccrust-via-lldb-vscode